# ao usar AJAX, posso enviar o conteúdo sem estar em volta da tag form?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

deve-se colocar os `inputs`, etc dentro de um `<form id="algo" method="POST"></form>`?

```
<form id="algo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="NADA" name="valor1" />
    <input type="text" value="TUDO" name="valor2" />
</form>
```

Ou posso mandar via ajax assim:

```
    <input type="text" value="NADA" name="valor1" />
    <input type="text" value="TUDO" name="valor2" />
```

O ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "algumaurl.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        valor1: $("[name='valor1']").val(),
        valor2: $("[name='valor2']").val(),
    },
    success: function(data){
        //faz algo
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes enviar AJAX como te convêm melhor. O que é importante é os dados que passas e como inicias o AJAX.

Os dados colocas aqui:

```
data: {
    valor1: $("[name='valor1']").val(),
    valor2: $("[name='valor2']").val(),
},
```

Assim, como fizeste está correto.

Se quiseres usar o evento `submit` de um `<form>` tudo bem, mas podes queres iniciar uma chamada AJAX de outra maneira. É irrelevante. O `<form>` não tem de estar presente para usares AJAX, ele faz sentido quando queres enviar um formulário para o servidor sem AJAX, e é somente útil para agrupar dados como em

```
data: $(form).serialize()
```